# Html.DisplayFor not Working For Boxed Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, boxing

I have an MVC4 razor view in which I am to displaying a table of data using reflection from metadata to dynamically build the columns at runtime. The int columns do not appear for @Html.DisplayFor, but do appear for string, bool etc. All columns seem to appear when using @Html.TextboxFor or just writing the value to the page. Visual Studio shows the type to be object{int} in the debugger which I am assuming is because of boxing.  My guess is that DisplayFor is keying off the type object{int} not int. Is there anyway to make this work without creating a new DisplayFor template for object{int}, if that is even possible?

```
@foreach (var item in words)
{
   <tr>
   @foreach (var prop in wordMeta.GetMetaProperties())
   {
      dynamic val = prop.GetInstanceValue(item);
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => val)</td>
   }
   </tr>
}
```

Comment: You ViewModel should be strongly-typed exactly as needed.  Sending any int value boxed as object in a ViewModel is definitely a [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Working on a RAD tool that can dynamically display whatever poco you give it. That's why I am using reflection.

Comment: So you want your tool to be able to automatically unbox a value type?

Comment: Yep. At runtime, before the DisplayFor template reflection evaluates. I could make the GetInstanceValue() method return Dynamic<int> but it needs to evaluate if before it selects the template.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to display just value and do not need any strong binding, then just use ***Raw*** template.

```
dynamic val = prop.GetInstanceValue(item);
<td>@Html.Raw(val)</td>
```

This would work with all datatypes.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is more about why DisplayFor does not work in this instance than how to make it display on the page.

Comment: In your scenario, you should declare the variable as "var" instead of "dynamic" because dynamic are dynamically typed variables and not strongly typed and DisplayFor template only works with strongly types.

Comment: It is dynamic as I am using reflection to display the columns of a object at run time. Other controls like TextBoxFor work with this, but DisplayFor does not. Probably matches on a template. How to get the boxed int to just be int?

Comment: The only possible way I can think ( not the most elegant way to do ) to get the int value from the box is to check the generated html/string from DisplayFor since @Html.DisplayFor doesn't generate any markup for int dataTypes.
This might just work for you :

dynamic val = prop.GetInstanceValue(item);
                                                               
if(@Html.DisplayFor(n => val).ToString() == "")
{
  var c = Convert.ToInt32(a) // Gets the int value;
}